# Get second variable of a foreach array in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

To clean it up, I put this question with a new topic.

I'm using the autocompleter of "http://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/" but in a previous version because of its lightweight and speed. the version I used can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/source/browse/

Within that I try to receive results with

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

$(function() {

$("#ac1").autocomplete('search.php', {
selectFirst: true
});

$("#flush").click(function() {
var ac = $("#ac1").data('autocompleter');
if (ac && $.isFunction(ac.cacheFlush)) {
    ac.cacheFlush();
} else {
    alert('Error flushing cache');
}
});
```

the data.php is simply structured:

```
$data = array(
"Berlin" => "10178",
"Hamburg" => "20038",
"München" => "80331",
```

and the search.php file contains the following:

```
<?php
include 'data.php';

function autocomplete_format($results) {
foreach ($results as $result) {
echo $result[0] . '|' . $result[1] . "\n";
}
}


if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
$q = strtolower($_GET['q']);
if ($q) {
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
        $results[] = array($key, $value);
    }
}
}
}

$output = 'autocomplete';
if (isset($_GET['output'])) {
$output = strtolower($_GET['output']);
}

if ($output === 'json') {
echo json_encode($results);
} else {
echo autocomplete_format($results);
}
```

Now I try, that after I chose the right city from the dropdown menu there will be the number right beside the city (in the data.php) in an new label.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: is your problem client side or server side? If it is client side please only post relevant code

Comment: @DanielBeck  As you see in the data.php there e.g. "Berlin" => "10178". in the dropdown-menu of the autocompleter I'd like to chose "Berlin" and now I try to find out how the Number "10178" will automatically put into a new textfield. Same when I chose "hamburg" then in a new field should be "20038" and so on and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $data['Berlin'];
```